# Attaching file not having the complete path name

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, path

Whenever I try to attach any file from HTML page in web browser(either Google chrome or Mozzila) and send to Servlet, I'm getting just getting the name of the file without having it's complete path.  If I make an attachment of any file from C drive, I'm not getting it's complete address. And whenever I try to send this file name to mail server, I'm getting an exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Hello.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1381)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:852)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:452)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:98)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1381)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1742)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:737)
    ... 18 more
```

How can I get rid of this problem? How to get the complete address of my uploaded file?

Comment: why do you need the complete path?

Comment: I need it because I want to send the mail as an attachment.

Comment: Suppose you got the path of that file. Now what can you do sitting on the server. You can't access the clients machine who uploaded the file. I hope you are getting my point.

Comment: Have you set the form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? How are you parsing the MIME data sent from the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you were to obtain the full path, it would be the path of the file on the client's machine, which the server has no access to.

If you want to store the uploaded file on the server, then you need to store the uploaded file on the local server filesystem, then pass that to the JavaMail API.